# 1992 Honda accord no headlights.

Tags: honda, accord, headlight

1992 Honda accord has no headlights. All fuses an relays are good . I've cleaned up all grounds I could find. Column stalks fine.But I've no current to both headlight fuse receptacles in fuse panel in engine compartment. So what's my next step.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you checked the relay?